# How to shorten Python code involving the sum of reciprocals?

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

I have a coding problem that goes like this:

> Given a positive integer \$N\$, return a list of all possible pairs of positive integers \$(x,y)\$ such that $$\frac1x+\frac1y=\frac1N$$

I already solved the problem using Python, but I was wondering how I can code golf it. The following is my attempt at golfing (I try to follow some tips on the tips page):

108 bytes

```python
exec("f=lambda N:[b for i in range(1,N+1)if N*N%i==0"+"for b in[%s,%s[::-1]]][:-1]"%(("[N+i,N+N*N//i]",)*2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYtBCgIhFED3nUIEQUdjxoYiBK/gBcSFltaHcsSZRZ3enF2r9xbvle/2XPJ8LbW1@Ik3ipN@@Xe4e2SUDSgtFQGCjKrPj0ilMFwySMgMhoDWE@Z4T0JPLFkFWa1SR@mcszswoRRbw6Fv/RhHcFiw4cTYoVTIG030/OfzZWKstR8)

Ungolfed code for better readability

```python
def f(N):
 l=[]
 for i in range(1,N+1):
  if N*N%i==0:
   a=[N+i,N+N*N//i]
   l.extend([a,a[::-1]])
 return l[:-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PclBCsMgEIXhvaeYTcFp0iYSGorgFbyAuBCi7YAYEQvt6W2E0t17358/9bmn5Z5La5sPELhGySAqYxmEvQABJSguPTwXox5Er0AB9FmfSKm5X3DK6IGOfOg0ke0Wr/5dfdq4caMzUl6Etcig@PoqCaLpwFgulCoP/Ib42/i3ZZ0RW/sC)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this a planned code-golf challenge? Not that I'm gonna plan a solution in advance, but it seems like a real nice challenge.

Comment: @ThisFieldIsRequired No, I was just wondering how I can golf my own code for this problem.

Comment: @AnttiP That works too... I guess I immediately approached the problem mathematically without thinking of brute force solutions.

Comment: Small correction: `f=lambda N:[(x,y)for x in range(1,N**3)for y in range(N**3)if(x+y)*N==x*y]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 60 bytes

```python
f=lambda N:[[N+i,N+N*N//i]for i in range(1,N*N+1)if 1>N*N%i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRwc8qOtpPO1PHT9tPy09fPzM2Lb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVXDUAcorm2omZmmYGgHZKpmxv4vKMrMK9FI0zDV1OSCsY3NDDQ1/wMA)

No need for reversing:

We just generate every fraction for which the first denominator is a divisor of N squared.

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess I got tunnel vision with the reversing thing. Also the if `1>N*N%i` is pretty smart too.

Comment: `//` can be `/` in Python 2 for -1 byte

Comment: @pxeger Yep! but I don't do python 2.

Comment: That just output `30.0` instead of `30` but maybe still reasonable?

Comment: I'm fine with outputting floats as long it end in `.0`.

Comment: You can save a byte by going `N*N+1->N**3`

Comment: @AnttiP Fail if N=1

Comment: @AnttiP So, maybe `3**N`?

Answer (score 3):

As AnttiP has pointed out, this can be shorter with a change of approach and full rewrite. Let's look at some simpler manipulations of your original code though just for the sake of it though:

Here was my first attempt at eliminating the `exec` hack:

#### 85 bytes

```
lambda N:[b for i in range(1,N+1)if N*N%i==0for b in[A:=[N+i,N+N*N//i],A[::-1]]][:-1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3Q3MSc5NSEhX8rKKTFNLyixQyFTLzFIoS89JTNQx1_LQNNTPTFPy0_FQzbW0NQPJJQPloRyvbaD_tTKA8UEpfPzNWxzHaykrXMDY2NhpEQQzfWVCUmVeikaZhqqnJBWMbmxloakLkFyyA0AA)

Unfortunately, as you may notice, it doesn't work, because `:=` is not allowed in `for` comprehension iterable expression.

There's another place we can put it in though: the `if` clause just before it:

#### 91 bytes

```
lambda N:[b for i in range(1,N+1)if(A:=[N+i,N+N*N//i])and N*N%i==0for b in[A,A[::-1]]][:-1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3o3MSc5NSEhX8rKKTFNLyixQyFTLzFIoS89JTNQx1_LQNNTPTNBytbKP9tDOBXD8tP339zFjNxLwUBSBbNdPW1gCkKwmoK9pRxzHaykrXMDY2NhpEQazYWVCUmVeikaZhqqnJBWMbmxloakLkFyyA0AA)

This can be shortened a bit by combining the comparison `==0`:

#### 89 bytes

```
lambda N:[b for i in range(1,N+1)if 0in(A:=[N+i,N+N*N//i],N*N%i)for b in[A,A[::-1]]][:-1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3I3MSc5NSEhX8rKKTFNLyixQyFTLzFIoS89JTNQx1_LQNNTPTFAwy8zQcrWyj_bQzgUJ-Wn76-pmxOkBaNVMTpCcJqCfaUccx2spK1zA2NjYaREEs2FlQlJlXopGmYaqpyQVjG5sZaGpC5BcsgNAA)

The `[:-1]` at the end is just to remove the final duplicated result of `(x, x)`, but we can remove this just by switching to a set comprehension (and using a tuple instead of a list, because it's hashable):

#### 84 bytes

```
lambda N:{b for i in range(1,N+1)if 0in(A:=(N+i,N+N*N//i),N*N%i)for b in[A,A[::-1]]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3Q3ISc5NSEhX8rKqTFNLyixQyFTLzFIoS89JTNQx1_LQNNTPTFAwy8zQcrWw1_LQzgUJ-Wn76-pmaOkBaNVMTpCcJqCfaUccx2spK1zA2thZi9s6Cosy8Eo00DVNNTS4Y29jMQFMTIr9gAYQGAA)

The output is no longer in order, so hopefully that doesn't matter here.

I'm working on going further than this... stay tuned

Comment: That's a nice trick to take out the walrus operator from the iterable expression! I couldn't figure out how to do that, so I resorted to the `exec` trick.